# Canary rollout between two k8s/gke namespaces by DNS cutover?

Tags: kubernetes, dns, google-kubernetes-engine, kube-dns, canary-deployment

I have two similar services/deployments/ingress running in two GKE/K8S namespaces: ns-A (old), ns-B (new). The ingress of ns-A is like `myservice.mycompany.com`. All clients are using `myservice.mycompany.com` to access old services in ns-A.

Now, I need to rollout the traffic from ns-A to ns-B. I need all clients to access the new service in ns-B. I can create a new Ingress for new service in ns-B: `myservice-B.mycompany.com` and update all service to use this new endpoint.

but I have many clients. it is possible to use other ways to do canaries rollout from ns-A to ns-B. I looked into contour, but contour cannot support two namespaces rollout.

is it possible to use DNS cutover or cluster-internal DNS names to canary rollout? Could you please give more details? Thanks

Comment: What ingress are you using? are you using any service mesh?

have you tried using flagger? https://docs.flagger.app/usage/deployment-strategies#canary-release

Answer (score 2):

You could implement canary on ingress level, rather than DNS one.
Say, fresh versions of `ingress-nginx` support canary deployments out of box.
https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#canary.

Great example here.
https://medium.com/@domi.stoehr/canary-deployments-on-kubernetes-without-service-mesh-425b7e4cc862

Note, that `ingress-nginx` canary implementation ***requires*** your services to be in different namespaces.

Comment: My two services are in two K8S namespaces. it is OK to use ingress-nginx?

Comment: Actually, `ingress-nginx` canary implementation ***requires*** your services to be in different namespaces. Just check the example I mentioned above.